# How can I make (Fold s a) from Control.Lens a monoid?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm fooling around with lenses and prisms and I've gotten into the weeds a bit. I want to write the following in template Haskell but as is it doesn't compile:

```
data Suit = Spade | Heart | Diamond | Club
makePrisms ''Suit
blackSuits = _Spade <> _Club
```

Everything I know about lenses and prisms (as well as comments in the `Getter` documentation) suggests that `_Spade <> _Club` should be a valid `Fold Suit ()`. But ghc can't compile the above code; it complains about several ambiguous instances. ghci gives me the following type signature for `_Spade <> _Club`:

```
_Spade <> _Club
  :: (Applicative f, Monoid (p Suit (f Suit)), Choice p) =>
     p () (f ()) -> p Suit (f Suit)
```

And by replacing `p` with `(->)` I can relax that type to

```
(Applicative f, Monoid (f Suit)) => (() -> f ()) -> Suit -> f Suit
```

The only difference between that and `Fold Suit ()` is that the latter has `(Applicative f, Contravariant f) => ...` instead of the `Monoid (f Suit)` restriction. When I read up on `Contravariant` I see assertions that `(Applicative f, Contravariant f)` together imply that `f` is actually `Const r` for some monoid `r`. That seems to suggest that the type above is actually a subset of `Fold Suit ()`. But when I try to add `blackSuits :: Fold Suit ()` to my code I get

```
Could not deduce (Monoid (f Suit)) arising from a use of ‘<>’
from the context (Contravariant f, Applicative f) ...
```

I get similar errors if I just try to define monoids on folds instead of starting with prisms. Nothing I've done to try and make `Fold s a` a `Monoid` passes the compiler. Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the `Fold` signature:

```
type Fold s a = forall f. (Contravariant f, Applicative f)=> (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
```

it says it has to work for **all** `f` that are `Contravariant` and `Applicative`. When you combine two folds together using `<>`, the `Semigroup` instance for functions `instance Semigroup b => Semigroup (a -> b)` requires that `f s` is `Semigroup`. That means it will no longer type check as a `Fold`. However, most (all?) functions that take a fold in `lens` will still accept this because they take a `Getting r s a = (a -> Const r a) -> s -> Const r s`, which this will type check for.

There's a couple of things you can do. You could use the [`Fold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-Reified.html#t:ReifiedFold) newtype which has its own `Monoid` instance:

```
> :set -XTemplateHaskell
> import Control.Lens
> import Data.Semigroup
> data Suit = Spade | Heart | Diamond | Club; makePrisms ''Suit
> let blackSuitsFold = runFold $ Fold _Spade <> Fold _Club :: Fold Suit ()
```

Or you could "clone" the fold:

```
> let cloneFold = foldring . foldrOf
> let blackSuitsClone = cloneFold $ _Spade <> _Club :: Fold Suit ()
```

or, if you don't need it to be a `Fold` you can use `Getting` synonym which would work the same in most cases:

```
> let blackSuitsGetter = _Spade `mappend` _Club :: Monoid r => Getting r Suit ()
> has blackSuitsGetter Spade
True
```

Comment: Ah, that's what "reified" folds are for! Thanks!